# How to delete RSS feeds from Yahoo Pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

In Pipes I created a RSS feed that I used in Google Reader. I used it to automate message posts to LinkedIn. But now I want to cancel it.

So, I deleted the Yahoo pipe, but RSS feeds are still posted. The old RSS link still remains in Pipes, while the Pipe doesn't exist anymore.

Any ideas how I can delete the RSS feeds in pipes?